# Add default options to anonymous list - Linq

Tags: c#, jquery, linq

I am binding dropdown list using my Linq query below.

```
var RecordList = objContext.Categories
    .Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.CatName, Value = c.CategoryId })
    .ToList();
```

Here, I also want one more options to add to listbox: -- Select -- with 0 value.

How can I modify above RecordList and add one more default option explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the properties on an anonymous type are the same name and type, the compiler will reuse the anonymous type.  This makes the answer quite simple:

```
var RecordList = objContext.Categories
    .Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.CatName, Value = c.CategoryId })
    .ToList();
RecordList.Insert(0, new { DisplayText = "-- Select --", Value = 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert item when bind list -

listItem.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));